# regular expression that use th previous pattern with awk

Tags: regex, linux, awk

This is content of my log file:

```
INFO consume_end_processor: user:bbbb callee_num:+23455539764806 sid:I374uribbbbb151101030212130 duration:0 result:ok provider:sipouthh.ym.ms
INFO consume_processor: user:bbbb callee_num:+23455539764806 sid:<<"A28udestaniephillips52x151031185754827">> duration:0 result:ok provider:sipouthh.ym.ms
```

and I need to extract the content from :

```
sid:<<"A28udestaniephillips52x151031185754827">>
sid:A28udestaniephillips52x151031185754827
```

like  `A28udestaniephillips52x151031185754827`

My answer is `awk '/(?<=sid)^[A-Z]+\/{print $8 }'`, however this is wrong and I am not sure how to fix it.

How can I write my regular expression in awk in order to extract just this part of information.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `awk { print $5 }`?

Comment: @Tom Fenech  hey, do u mean $8 ? I need to sort based on the sid.

Comment: From your example, it looks like that part you're interested in is the fifth field.

Comment: yes, you right, I didn't copied complete example.;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ sub(/^sid:(<<")?/,"",$5); sub(/">>$/, "", $5); print $5}' log.txt
I374uribbbbb151101030212130
A28udestaniephillips52x151031185754827
```

Here we are simply using `sub` to remove (by replacing with an empty string) the parts of the 5th field that we don't want.

The first `sub` removes the leading `sid:`, that may optionally be followed by `<<"`.

The second `sub` removes a trailing `">>`. Note that if there is no trailing `">>`, then the `sub` does nothing and is harmless.

Comment: thank you for your answer, Is that possible to explain in your answer a little bit what you have done?

Comment: Of course, see edit. If anything still not clear, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/sid:(<<")?|">>/,"",$5); print $5}' file
I374uribbbbb151101030212130
A28udestaniephillips52x151031185754827
```

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton, I see that your solution is working too. If you can give some explanation about your solution and its priority to the previous one I will be appreciated.

Comment: IMHO it's already extremely clear but what do **you** think it does and I'll tell you if you're right or wrong?